# How to detect mobile or tablet device without external libs using JS/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, device

Is there any way how to detect if user is on mobile device or tablet device without external libs using javascript? And how?

I am using React (**not** react-native).

Comment: React is not JQuery.

Comment: Did you read the linked question? The first answer also answers the question for native JS.

Comment: you can calculate the screen size by javascript  link is here 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp